# Using Stomp and Apache ActiveMQ as reliable syslog

Tags: logging, messaging, activemq-classic, syslog

One of my programs requires a reliable way to log across unreliable network (ie internet). The sender or receiver may go offline any time and can come back later. But any message sent by client should not be missed. Obviously syslog does not fit the bill. I am exploring the use of messaging servers like Apache ActiveMQ instead of syslog. Message senders are in perl, ruby and c. So I have Stomp as the message transport.

Does this serve my purpose? Is there any pitfall I am missing here?

raj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That all sounds fine to me

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [syslog-ng](http://www.balabit.com/network-security/syslog-ng/) which has a tcp mode. This allows for reliable delivery, but you have to make sure you configure it correctly.